# Maven dependencies not found

Tags: java, minecraft

my pom.xml is not working and is giving me errors that my dependencies are not found.
Here's my [pom.xml](https://paste.md-5.net/cecepebali.xml)

Is there anything I need to add or remove?

I really don't know as this is my first time using maven.

Comment: Can you show more informations about the issue ? Where are you stuck ? Can you show logs ?

Comment: The dependencies might be elsewhere.  Add additional repositories to .m2/settings.xml

Comment: Here's an image: https://imgur.com/a/d27kQcD
My new pom.xml: https://paste.md-5.net/oloqozined.xml
The dependency i am trying to add: https://github.com/kangarko/Foundation/
And it still doesn't work.